# Show user information firebase with google sign in button?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I am trying to **retrieve** the *user's information (name, email, etc)* once they sign in with google using firebase. I have been looking through the docs but can't find anything for Swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly From [Firebase Doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users)

```
let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
if let user = user {
  // The user's ID, unique to the Firebase project.
  // Do NOT use this value to authenticate with your backend server,
  // if you have one. Use getTokenWithCompletion:completion: instead.
  let uid = user.uid
  let email = user.email
  let photoURL = user.photoURL
  // ...
} else { // this else is not from doc
  // no user is connected / signed in / logged in.
}
```